# One error till it works...how to fix?

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main () // print to console: 3.0*5.0=15.00
{
    double a;
    double b;
    a =(3.0);
    b =(5.0);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "* " << b << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << a*b << "\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}

int calculate () // print to console: (7.1*8.3)-2.2=56.73
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    a = (7.1);
    b = (8.3);
    c = (2.2);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "* " << b << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "- " << c << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << (a*b)-c << "\n" << endl;
}
int calculation () // print to console: 3.2/(6.1*5.0)=0.10
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    a=(3.2);
    b=(6.1);
    c=(5.0);
    cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
    cout << b << "*" << c << endl; //how can I use variables instead of using quotes?
    cout << "------" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(2) << a/(b*c) << "\n" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

What does this output error mean? How do I fix it? someone please explain this to me. Am I suppose to add: `int calculate(int a, int b, int c)`?

Output:

```
(32): error C4716: 'calculate' : must return a value
```

Comment: so if I add 1) int main ()--->return a*b; 2) calculate ()--->return (a*b)-c; and 3) calculation ()--->return a/(b*c).....this should fix things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your function as one that returns an `int` value but there's no `return` statement.  Try changing the declaration to `void calculate()` if you don't need to return a value from it.

Comment: when I add:1) int main ()--->return a*b; 2) calculate ()--->return (a*b)-c; and 3) calculation ()--->return a/(b*c); this doesn't seem to get the program to work.....it also doesn't work when change everything but the first function return a*b;

Comment: @mariecamacho What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What error message do you receive?

Comment: I'm sorry for being vague. Here they are if I understood this I wouldn't be asking lol: Symbols loaded.
Loaded. Cannot find or open the PDB file
 LoadedCannot find or open the PDB file
Loaded Cannot find or open the PDB file
 LoadedSymbols loaded.
 Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[1504]: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: @mariecamacho That sounds like normal status messages dumped to the Visual Studio output window.  If you are attempting to run your program with the "Start Debugging" command (F5), it's likely running successfully then closing before you get a chance to see the output.  Try running it using the "Start Without Debugging" command (Ctrl + F5).

Answer (score 0):

The `calculate` function needs to return a value.
You need to add something like this at the end of `calculate`:

```
return (a*b)-c;
```

Comment: I don't know it doesen't seem to be making a large difference. On top of that the program is flashing too; I thought the system ("PAUSE") would fix that...hmmmm

Comment: @mariecamacho Note that you are not using the `calculate` or the `calculation` functions anywhere. Your program is just running the code in `main`.

Comment: oh ic would adding: 1) int main ()--->return a*b; 2) calculate ()--->return (a*b)-c; and 3) calculation ()--->return a/(b*c); fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's only because your calculate function is supposed to return an `int`
and there's no return in your function.

if you don't want to return anything, you can put `void calculate()` instead